# CSV file parsing based on a filed condition in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

My file contains these fields 
FirstName,LastName,DOB,SSN,Telephone,Status,ValidtoTime

and i want to extract the first name and ValidtoTime column .and the extracted data should contain First name of the user who will be expired in next one month from current date .

Please help me with this ,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shell programming, should go to Unix.SE

Comment: @vonbrand: I am not sure that shell *programming* should go to Unix.SE. Actually, I am pretty sure it *is* topical for SO, as Unix.SE is mostly about *using* and *configuring* Unix / Linux, whereas this here is *programming*.

Comment: @DevSolar, it is a question on using Unix tools.

Comment: @vonbrand: Is it? glenn's answer is using shell builtins only. Just because shell is a *Unix* programming environment shouldn't push shell questions off to a (primarily user / admin oriented) Unix.SE, IMHO, just as you shouldn't push Perl, GCC or Make questions there because "they're Unix tools". (FWIW, [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=shell+programming) seems to agree with me.)

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
while IFS=, read -ra fields; do
    : # do stuff
done < filename
```

will loop over the file, and store the comma-separated words in an array named `fields`. The first name will be in `"${fields[0]}"` and the valid-to time will be `"${fields[6]}"

Use the `date` command to parse the time field and to get the current time. Do some arithmetic.

If you have further questions, please show us what you've tried and what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using awk on something like this.
An easy example that is similar to your problem:

```
~/local/tmp » cat csv.txt
1,2,3
4,2,7
9,1,1
~/local/tmp » awk -F, '$3 > 2 {print $1,$3}' csv.txt 
1 3
4 7
```

To clarify what I did here:

-F, specifies the separator to be ','

'$3 > 2' is the condition that needs to be satisfied. I am checking that the entry in the third column is larger than 2. This needs to be modified according to the way you store your ValidtoTime. If in need for more help, please specify this. Also show your efforts and share what is not satisfying about them.

'{print}' prints the first and third entry of each row.

If you need to skip n rows (e.g. 1 row for a header), do:

```
tail -k+n csv.txt | awk -F, '$3 > 2 {print $1, $3}'
```

This should help you solve your problem. If there are still questions, please be more specific on the way ValidtoTime is formatted.